# CodeIgniter giving 404 on a webserver

Tags: php, codeigniter

I loaded my codeigniter site onto my actual webserver (instead of just local). I am getting a 404 page not found even from the root domain. On my localhost it works fine.

Try going to `searchnwork.com` and it gives the Codeigniter 404. How can I start debugging this and seeing what page CodeIgniter thinks it's loading?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `config file` and check the `base_url setting`
or add this

```
$config['base_url']='http://searchnwork.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into /application/logs/ folder  (this catalog must be writable to logs could be written). Check if you have model and controllers names in lowercase - it's common problem especially if you've moved site from Windows server.

Comment: Check if value of 'threshold' in application/config/config.php is set to > 0.

Answer (score 0):

do you have access to the PHP log and Apache log - check if its firing errors on both ends.